# What is best practice for handling application configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, settings

I'll phrase the question in the context of my application but I think it does have a wider scope generally for configuration. My application allows companies to track absences and holidays for its employees. One of the benefits is that it will automatically increase a person's holiday entitlement based on rules set by the employer. The intention is for the company to choose between:

A) automatically increase an employee's entitlement by a set number of days every year e.g. on 1 January each year, holiday entitlement increases by 1 day; or

B) an employee's entitlement increases based on length of service e.g. after 2 years' employment, entitlement increases by 2 days

What is the best way to implement this functionality? The first option is fairly simple to implement as I have track the start/end dates of each leave year and the increment for each employee can be stored as an integer.

I guess I'm looking for best practice solutions to store the chosen method; how to store the relevant options and all in an extensible format allowing me to add further methods later.

I'm working with Ruby on Rails but the question is probably relevant to other languages.

Thanks

Robin

Comment: Would the employer be able to set different rules for different employees? Or is it just one rule for everyone that changes from time to time?

Comment: I'd say one rule that applies to all employees. Different rules per employee is an edge case that I don't want to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

What about: Store the balance in Employee. Employee belongs to Company. When the time comes, set the balance by using something like

```
self.company.set_balance(self.balance)
```

So your employee assessor runs over all the employees and asks the company to recalculate its balance.

If it's a global policy, then you don't need to tell Company who the employee is, but if you needed to have special cases, you could pass the Employee to the set_balance method so that it would have more information about the employee being recalculated.

As for the Compay's strategy in how to increase the days, I'd put it in a model to limit the code changes needed if the strategy is changed.

If it's a simple rule, maybe just keep it in a key/value pair:

"holiday_entitlement"/"flat"
or
"holiday_entitlement"/"length of service"

I would not keep the the values (1 or 2) in the DB in order to avoid smart employees hacking into the DB and putting 'favourable' values in there :)